# Why does my programme take so long to run?

Tags: bash

I've written a small programme in bash that transforms multiple (tabbed) lines, with six columns, into a single line, with 12 columns as below:

```
    $1          $2      $3          $4          $5  $6      $7      $8      $9  $10     $11     $12
input
Scaffold952 345718  345781  aug3.g8795.t1   .   -
Scaffold952 346504  346534  aug3.g8795.t1   .   -
Scaffold952 346721  346733  aug3.g8795.t1   .   -
Scaffold952 348148  348241  aug3.g8795.t1   .   -
output
Scaffold952 345718  345781  aug3.g8795.t1   .   -   345718  345718  0   4   63,30,12,93 0,786,1003,2430
```

To complete this:

1. Take six column input, sort by name (col 4) then by start (col2)
2. Generate a list of names from the input and remove duplicates
3. foreach line generated in step 2

   - find corresponding lines in the input
   - use columns two and three to build columns 11 and 12, insert values into arrays
   - combine columns and arrays to form final, 12 column output
4. Insert into output file

Column 11 is comprised of $3 - $2; column 12 is comprised of $2 minus the first $2 value (345718), for each 6 column line and printed as csv.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
output=$2
> $output
# functions
function joinArray { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
# sort input
sort -k4,4 -k2,2 -o $input < $input

    awk '{ print $4 }' $input | uniq | while read -r line; do
        dup="$(grep -c $line $input)"
        start="$(grep $line $input | awk 'NR==1 { print $2 }')"
        records="$(grep $line $input | awk 'NR==1 { print $0 }')"

        grep $line $input | {
        while read -r record; do
            blocksize+=($(awk '{ print $3 - $2 }' <<< "$record"))
            blockstart+=($(awk -v var="$start" '{ print $2 - var }' <<< "$record"))
        done
#       combine input with arrays to form 12 col output
        bed12[0]+=$(awk '{ print $1 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[1]+=$(awk '{ print $2 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[2]+=$(awk '{ print $3 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[3]+=$(awk '{ print $4 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[4]+=$(awk '{ print $5 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[5]+=$(awk '{ print $6 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[6]+=$(awk '{ print $2 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[7]+=$(awk '{ print $2 }' <<< "$records")
        bed12[8]+='0'
        bed12[9]+=$dup
        bed12[10]+=$(joinArray $',' "${blocksize[@]}")
        bed12[11]+=$(joinArray $',' "${blockstart[@]}")

        joinArray $'\t' "${bed12[@]}" >> $output
        }
    done
```

So far I have been unable to make this code run efficiently, I'm looking to improve it as for a standard sized file (~30,000 lines) it took three hours to complete. I'm not sure what is causing the problems maybe opening/closing the output file every time a record is written; nested while loops; arrays? Is this a bad programme, the language not a suitable choice, or is this expected for a file that is this large (1.7 MB)?

Comment: Ye gawds. You run *how* many external programs for every single line processed?! How would you expect that to **not** be slow?!

Comment: Short form: It's possible to write sorta-kinda decently performing software in bash (easier with ksh93), but you're starting with a huge handicap and need to know what you're doing. It's much, much easier to choose a different language.

Comment: That poor `$input` file is read at least five times in its entirety for each scaffold...

Comment: There are also some other issues that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- `awk` is a full-featured programming language in its own right. To use it for nothing but picking out individual columns of text is something of a travesty.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a BED6 file to a BED12 file?  Doesn't [BEDTools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/bedtools-suite.html) have some utility for doing that for you? I'm unfamiliar with them, so can't point to any. Maybe `bedToBam` and then `bamToBed -bed12`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to keep in mind:

- Everything you put inside your `while read` loop runs once for every line processed.
- Running `$(...)` does a fork() call, creating a whole new process tree entry, runs your enclosed code in that new process, reads its stdout, and waits for the process to complete. That's a *lot* of overhead.
- Every time you run `awk` -- though it's a very fast language interpreter -- or `grep`, you're actually starting a new program: Forking it off, dynamically loading its library dependencies, wiring up its stdin and stdout... that's a lot of overhead too.
- Every time you do a redirection, such as `>>foo`, that's *opening the output file* for the command with the redirection on it, and then closing it again after that single file is complete. (This is specifically true for shell languages; some `awk` implementations of `>` cache and reuse file descriptors, notably including the GNU one).
- Unfortunately, as of this writing, the bash implementation of `<<<` involves creating a temporary file on disk. If using this construct in a tight inner loop on a platform where `/dev/fd` is a supported interface, `< <(printf '%s' "$foo")` thus may be faster than `<<<"$foo"` -- though I wouldn't advise actually doing that in practice unless you need it, as future versions of bash hopefully will address that behavior and do the right thing with the easier-to-read syntax.

---

So, what can you do?

- For tools such as `awk`, use them only when you can have a single, long-running instance reused across multiple lines of input.

  *Frankly, this is the most important recommendation here. Move all the work out of bash into a single `awk` invocation, and you'll be done.*
- For parsing an input stream into multiple fields, use bash's own builtins:

  ```
  read -r first_field second_field third_field ...
  ```
- Do your redirections at an enclosing outer scope, either with `exec >foo` to redirect stdout for the whole program (or entire subshell, if performed in such a context), or putting `>foo` after the `done` closing a loop to redirect stdout for the duration of that loop.

Comment: Don't run a tight loop over `>>outfile` but put `>outfile` after `done` instead.